# Django template extension: How do I best build a basenavbar that is also modifiable?

Tags: django

Okay, so here is what I am currently doing:

I am building a basetemplate, which defines a header, maindiv, navbar and a footer.
In all the templates extending that one all you have to define is the actual content of what goes in your main content. That worked quite well, since all the navbar contained were links to the model-list-view and model-create-view.

Now, when I am in the model list view, I want to be able to sort the list by a status and I wanted to add that ability to the navbar. I wonder how to go about this best, since the only template needing this new behaviour is the list view. The other templates shall remain unchanged.

Could I just add another {% block filter_thingie %} {% endblock %} into the navbar I have now and fill it only in the listview?

I am still a little unsure about the best way to structure my templates. In the "worst" case I could always just make a second navbar just for the listview I guess, but I kind of wanted to avoid that.

(parts of) The basetemplate:

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">

          <li><a href="/list-view" class="active">All objects of model</a></li>
          <li><a href="/create-view">Create new object of model</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
        {% block order_content %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Yeah, so it might be that I am just thinking way to complicated here, but I definitely want to keep the structure nice and not repeat myself if I don't have to.

I appreciate all the input, thanks for reading. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pull the whole nav-bar section out into its own block, you can override that only in the template you need to.

```
<!-- base.html -->
{% block navbar %}
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">

    <li><a href="/list-view" class="active">All objects of model</a></li>
    <li><a href="/create-view">Create new object of model</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}

<!-- list.html -->
{% block navbar %}
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">

    <li><a href="/list-view" class="active">All objects of model</a></li>
    <li><a href="/create-view">Create new object of model</a></li>
    <li>My filter thingie</li>
  </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

On the other hand, if you're happy for extra items to always go at the end, it would be better to - as you say - just put an empty block in the base template after the last of the site-wide nav items, and override that. (Although I'd maybe make the name more generic than filter_thingie, anticipating the inevitable occasion when something else needs to go in that slot...)

Comment: Haha, filter thingie wasn't supposed to be the final name. :) Thank you very much!